# UISearchController example crashes if animated = NO

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uikit, uisearchcontroller

I want to use the new UISearchController and I downloaded the Obj-C example provided by apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html

At line 123 of APLMainTableViewController.m we have the method executed when we tap on a row in the tableview

```
123   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
124        APLProduct *selectedProduct = (tableView == self.tableView) ?
125            self.products[indexPath.row] : self.resultsTableController.filteredProducts[indexPath.row];
126
127        APLDetailViewController *detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"APLDetailViewController"];
128        detailViewController.product = selectedProduct; // hand off the current product to the detail view controller
129
130        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
131
132        // note: should not be necessary but current iOS 8.0 bug (seed 4) requires it
133        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
134    }
```

If at line 130, I change the "animated:YES" into "animated:NO", the app will crashes in the following situation (I made the test in the iOS simulator for a iPhone 5s / iOS 8)

- type something in the search box, for example "iPod"
- tap on the first row in the search result. It will push the iPod detail view
- now tap the navigation button "< search" to return to the search controller
- the table view appears without the search box and the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Can somebody reproduces the problem and have any clue on why this is happening?

Edited: Apple's Bug Report #18859420

Answer (score 0):

> sub-question: the lines 132 and 133 note a bug in iOS 8.0. How can I know this bug is already solved or not?

Assuming you have filed a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com for the issue, you can ask for status updates from ADC via radar.

Furthermore, please report the radar number in an edit to your question.